# Filling missing value with word from list on condition

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

i'm trying to preprocess data especially dealing with missing values.
I have a list of words and two columns having text data. If word from list is in at least one of two text-columns, i fill missing with the word

```
import pandas as pd
a=['coffee', 'milk', 'sugar']
test=pd.DataFrame({'col':['missing', 'missing', 'missing'],
                   'text1': ['i drink tea', 'i drink coffee', 'i drink whiskey'],
                   'text2': ['i drink juice', 'i drink nothing', 'i drink milk']
                   })
```

So the dataframe looks like and a column "col" has "missing" as a result of applying fillna("missing")

```
Out[19]: 
       col            text1            text2
0  missing      i drink tea    i drink juice
1  missing   i drink coffee  i drink nothing
2  missing  i drink whiskey     i drink milk
```

I came up with such code applying loop

```
for word in a:
    test.loc[(test["col"]=='missing') & ((test["text1"].str.count(word)>0) 
    | (test['text2'].str.count(word)>0)), "col"]=word
```

With 100 000 rows and 2000 element in the list "a" it takes around 870 seconds to finish the job.
Is there any solution to make it faster for a huge dataframe?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `pandas` here? You might want to remove a few of the tags not necessary here and add that one - look to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Which column are you referring having missing values?

Comment: Column "col" has "missing" as a result of applying fillna("missing")

Comment: Provide sample data to get assist. Look around how other ppl do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Why use `.str.count` instead of `.str.contains`?
- Why do the `fillna('missing')`? `pd.isnull(test["col"])` will work faster tan `test["col"]=='missing'`
- You could also use a test to see whether all the missing fields are filled.

So this can boil down to something like this:

```
def fill_missing(original_df, column_name, replacements, inplace=True):
    df = original_df if inplace else original_df.copy()
    for word in replacements:
        empty = pd.isnull(df[column_name])
        if not empty.any():
            return df
        contained = (df.loc[empty, "text1"].str.contains(word))  | (df.loc[empty, 'text2'].str.contains(word))
        df.loc[contained[contained].index, column_name] = word
    return df
```

Comment: Changing "count" to "contains" helps to save a bit of time. I'll rewrite my code to try pd.isnull(test["col"]). Thank you

Comment: Thank you again! Your code makes real change in handling the problem and works almost 2 times faster!!!